# android listview select from top with problems

Tags: android, listview, webview

I add header view to listview ,and there is a webview in header to show local html content,and listview shows comments.
I user selectFromTop after adapter has finished load data in order to show first comment item,but some times it doesn't work,what's wrong??

Comment: show some code please...